# How can I fix these Linter Issues in Atom?

Tags: html, css, atom-editor, linter

I'm currently learning WebDev with an Instructor from Udemy and I noticed that the behavior of my Atom is not the same as here (Even though I installed the same packages as she did).

> The following pictures are from the instructor's screen

- When I create an error like the picture below, I get a linter suggestion at the bottom, however, I do not get the pop-up annotation like the picture: [Picture1](https://i.ibb.co/yWjmN5v/2021-04-04-08-46-35-1424b25563c64f526628bafb1e2058a0.png)
- I also do not receive an alphabetical order suggestion like the picture below in CSS either:
  [Picture2](https://i.ibb.co/Pcxt7Zg/2021-04-04-08-49-40-33011cd6c94c8f173cdaf9ffe732d372.png)
- I don't receive any errors on HTML pages or see a red dot on the left like this:
  [Picture3](https://i.ibb.co/TYTg9XC/2021-04-04-09-22-04-ee0267c243e8f3c6b53e677d758ec0ec.png)

Instructor's Packages (besides the default ones) : [Atom Packages](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQNuhDC5pFXEVVNGasvddKuDHEXnqR033lsSD5tLA9NiEdHrsYM4MXVEXja2RnBgsCxK6XEo6YkMOFI/pub)

```
        How can I fix my atom linter?
```

PS: I did write in the Q&A section of the course but no reply, I'm on Windows 10 if it makes a difference (the instructor is using a mac).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: 1: `color: red;` You can ignore the 2nd one. Third one is not easy to say without seeing the error code or type.

Comment: @m4n0 I understand the mistake, it was a testing mistake.
What I'm trying to achieve is to get the same linter behavior as my instructor's device.

Answer (score 1):

In the first one you should use

`h1 { color: red; }`

instead of:

`h1 { color red; }`

---

With number two I am not quite sure what is meant there and that's why I don't want to say anything wrong.

---

In number 3, 2 same Id's were used. If you want to use more than one then you should use `class` instead of `id`. In CSS you address id's with `#` and classes with `.`.

Comment: I'm not interested in the coding error, please read the question carefully @gucciBananaKing99
It is about the Atom Editor, the linter is not functioning properly.

Comment: @Wishy Sorry I just misread the question. Could you please check if you have an older version? I haven't used Atom for a few years and there were no error messages etc. After the update everything was there

Comment: I installed it 4 days ago from their website, and I have all of the packages updated to the latest version as well (checked today), tbh I have no clue how could my linter behave so horribly on a new install, could it be some setting I need to turn on or a shortcut I need to use to show that toolbox thing? I just don't know anymore.

Comment: turns out because of node.js was not installed and running nothing was working, now it is.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was all because Node.JS was not installed.

Once I installed it and ran it, everything started to work.